# Unity: Do I have to learn one, or both (C#, UnityScript)

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I originally thought that one had to know both C# as well as UnityScript to develop using Unity. But it now seems that I only need to know one. So,

1. Do both the languages do similar things and hence I should code in one, or should I learn them both as I'm supposed to use both?
2. Does Unity *only* use C# and/or UnityScript cuz I always thought games *had* to use at least 2, even in Wikipedia, it's written as if it's a definition or something. (I know some games can be made solely using pygame and stuff, but I mean things like AAA titles).
3. ***Continuing from 2*** Or is it that you *do* use more than just C# and/or UnityScript in case of using Unity, and Unity is only for certain parts of the game?

Comment: Better get Unity and start playing with it, then you will see what you need to learn, just follow the tutorials. There's no fixed rule for AAA games, some are written in C++, other in Visual c++ .net, others in C#, others in java, others mix multiple languages...

Comment: The old philosophy that AAA games must be written in c/c++ using say Unreal is dying, particularly when you consider games like _Cities: Skylines_ and _Kerbal Space Program_ are made with Unity.

Comment: so what ive heard of people saying they use 3+ programming languages to make games, it's not really always true, like i heard valve uses just c++?

Comment: hi @NeelKamath.  You are totally misinformed.  Unity is c# and that's it.  (There was a thing called "unityscript" available. It is deprecated. You can not use it now.)

Comment: Regarding your question 3, you make games in Unity.  You use (only) c# to write "behaviors" for the game objects.  It's that simple.  Suggest you just click to download Unity to get the idea.  It would take you less time than asking this question.

Comment: By the way Neel, this question will likely be closed here.  The site you're looking for for questions like this is **gamedev.com**

Comment: @JoeBlow thx, I'll check the site out.

Comment: As I say below @NeelKamath don't hesitate to ask more questions.  I just now put in some long comments below, to try to further clarify the issues. It seems to me that the main confusion is this: the ***"stuff"*** in games (the models, drawings, animations and so on) have utterly no connection to Unity and the programmers.  If you go to a big game company, there are 300 **artists** who make models of humans, guns, mario, Lara Croft, roads, monsters, and so on. There might be only 25 engineers. The engineers use Unity (and c#).  The **artists** have utterly no connection to Unity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## "unityscript" *is deprecated*.

## You must use c#.  It's that simple.

---

From my very limited development in Unity:

**It's an either or thing.**

I've written quick test-of-skill games using only C# as I'm more familiar with it from previous knowledge of C and C++. While reading the docs to decide whether or not I would try to port code over to the UnityScript code (again, as a test of skill), it became my understanding that either way you get the end result you want.

In these games I wrote all sorts of components, including UI, game object, terrain collision, even fiddling with jumping and the gravity engine. Never once did I have to stop and go "well darn. Looks like I need to use Unity Script for this."

Games in Unity, as far as I am aware, *can* use both. But I've never been forced into having to use one or the other.

If you ever run into a part where Unity forces you to use both, go ahead and come back to this post to yell at me.

Comment: thanks! so as i understand it, it's basically a preference of which you want to code in. but, how come i always hear big companies using so many languages? is it that game engines like unity support many languages and it's more efficient in certain places? or they don't use game engines? or they can't actually use unity to make the *whole* game, which is why we don't always see games ported to all systems even though unity claims they can be?

Comment: The porting thing from games tends to be a license restriction. In order to develop a game, (again, with my very limited knowledge) is that you need to apply for a license for that console. There's a ton of reasons why you would only license something to one system, probably some variety of deal made with the parent company. I'm unsure what you mean by the rest of the questions.

Comment: i meant if unity only supports 2 languages how come i hear (with the exception of valve apparently only using c++) developers using more than 1 or 2 languages?

Comment: @NeelKamath This answer is a little but misleading. Just use C#. Unityscript will be killed very soon. Once C# 6.0 is made available for Unity, it will likely no longer be available. Most companies hire people with C# skills not Unityscript. New Unity examples are only available in C#.  You don't need to know Unityscript for any reason. For C++, you can make plugins with it  in Unity. You still need to call that plugin from C#. So C# is required.

Comment: @Programmer ok thank you for the information. so are you saying that i developers *do* in fact *need* to use languages other than C# to make AAA games and use them in game engines such as unity through plugins or whatever?

Comment: @NeelKamath You only need to know C# for Unity. Yes, C# can be used to make AAA games. The only time you use C++ or make a plugin is when a feature you require is not available in Unity. For example, lets say you want to blink the keyboard Caps Lock LED, there is Unity API for that. You make it in C++, convert it into DLL and call the DLL functions from Unity C#.  Another example is when you are doing complicated or advanced stuff such modifying textures in real-time or generating mesh in real-time, this is very slow in Unity.

Comment: @NeelKamath You can make it faster by using pointers in C# but it is still slower than using C++. C++ seems to be able to handle multiple for loops very fast. Also generating a procedural texture should be done in C++ and all these I've said is only for performance reasons. It can still be done in C#. At the end of the day, you still need to call it from C#. **AAA games must be written in c/c++** That's not true. Just learn about managing memory in C# and how to avoid garbage collection because garbage collection in C# and Java is why most people say this. **AAA** can be done with C#.

Comment: @Programmer what I understood from what you said is that i can make (at least a basic) game using *just* Unity. But now Mohammad Faizan Khan is saying you can't actually make the game in it, that's why it's only in C#. You make the characters, logic etc. elsewhere and just combine it all there..? Soo?

Comment: @Jhecht  *"From my very limited development in Unity:..."*  I don't mean to be rude, but why answer?

Comment: Because the Internet is more willing to prove someone wrong than answer a question.

Comment: @JoeBlow I have Unity, but I didn't see anybody say anything 'bout UnityScript like this, that's why I went on to ask the question. Not to be rude, but if I had known all the answers to my "nonsensical, confusion piled on confusion" questions, I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: You're all set now @NeelKamath.  Enjoy c# programming.  It is all you need, you need nothing else. You were very simply mistaken about games "having to use" more than one language.  Large companies may happen to use various languages *on different projects* - for example Unity jobs use c#, whereas iPhone jobs use "Swift", and web-programming jobs use things like PHP. As a curiosity, in Unity you can use an obscure language called "Boo", or c#, but everyone uses c#.  Everything you do with Unity will be c#.  Enjoy.

Comment: To try to explain further @NeelKamath. You said: *"...i can make (at least a basic) game using just Unity."*  Note that for example many versions of ***Angry Birds*** are made with Unity (ie with c#).  You could easily make *Grand Theft Auto* using Unity (they happen to use a different system).  If you look at the top selling lists on the app stores, of the 100 biggest sellers 70+ are made with Unity.  It's the basic system used to make games today.

Comment: one final poit @NeelKamath.  You seem to be confused about ***"ASSETS"***.  To make video games, you use things like ***music, songs, paintings, illustrations, models, animations, and drawings***. Right?  Generally you hire experts to do these things, obviously. (Unless, by an amazing coincidence, you're a famous musician, artist or whatever.)  So, for a client, we had a famous pop star make some music.  Obviously, that was done in a recording studio (using "ProTools" - or whatever), and has **utterly no connection** to Unity.  You understand?  Similarly .....

Comment: ... similarly, glance at the famous illustrations on games like Angry Birds, Fieldrunners or the like.  These are done by industry artists (incredibly well-paid!) and of course to do that they use tools like Illustrator, Sketch, Painter and so on.  Obviously that has ***utterly no connection*** to Unity. Similarly, think of all the ***models*** in all the 3D games you play - so, cars, spaceships, guns, Lara Croft, your character in Doom or whatever.  Obviously, those models are made by experts using Blender, Maya, Mixamo, 3DSMax, ZBrush, etc etc etc....

Comment: ... again obviously that has **absolutely nothing** to do with Unity.  I think you may have some confusion: at a game company you have a whole lot of artists ***who make the models, drawings, music and the like***. Of course, they do that using things like Blender, Photoshop and the like - you know?  That has absolutely no connection at all to Unity.  In a whole separate department, ***the actual programmers sit there, using Unity*** and they take those things (models, animations, drawings, music, etc), they put those things **in to** Unity and then program games.

Comment: Hopefully this makes some sense to you.  Enjoy.  If you have further questions, just ask them here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much use whichever language you're most comfortable with. There will be the odd asset that uses one language when you prefer another. If you want to use and tweak the functionality of that asset, you'll need to do so in their language.

The scripts work in tandem and both can exist within a given project at the same time. Doing this can get messy as evidenced by this issue:

[Unity3d: Accessing JS variable from c# and vice versa](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/48874/accessing-javascript-variable-from-c-and-vice-vers.html)

I believe some of the basic freely available assets are in UnityScript such as the character controller. If you're planning to use one of these heavily and will need to communicate with those scripts regularly, it may inform your language decision. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Too many question in a single post, well try to provide answer accordingly.

> 1. Do both the languages do similar things

Answer: In Programming, Theoretically, mathematically, strictly, yes. They're all equivalent.
In practice, no, they vary fairly wildly. [ref](https://www.quora.com/Do-all-programming-languages-do-the-same-thing-but-in-different-ways-or-are-they-used-for-different-purposes)

> I should code in one, or should I learn them both as I'm supposed to
>   use both?

Answer: I would say it depends very much on your past experience. If your background is in C++ or Java, you will likely feel most at home in C# - however if you're experienced with dynamically typed languages such as JavaScript / Basic or PHP, chances are you will prefer JavaScript.

If you have no previous experience with programming - JavaScript might be an easier introduction - given that you do not need to worry about types and casting.[ref](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7528/how-should-i-decide-if-i-should-use-c-javascript-u.html)

> Does Unity only use C# and/or UnityScript cuz I always thought games
>   had to use at least 2

Answer: absolutely not mandatory, much depends upon you expertise, requirement, teams strength and management.

> Unity is only for certain parts of the game?

Answer: Absolutely yes, unity allow you to build, do lighting and provide some particle effects(if require). it not allow you complex modelling it provide interface to programming even mono-developer is a separate application.

helpful links:

1. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/what-are-the-pro-cons-of-unity3d-as-a-choice-to-make-games
2. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-pros-and-cons-of-Unity-3D-and-Unreal-Engine

Comment: so i'd need to use things other than unity for character design etc. and unity is just for the logic or making it look nice?

Comment: even you can't use it for your logic, you program in a separate application like mono developer tool or vs.

Comment: professionally all models are develop in specific modelling tools like max Maya, blender etc. design is a separate art+science . you just import it in unity in order to finalize your product

Comment: in our company, practically we brings our models/animation into unity, do somecoding, Apply some shaders and lighting, adjust some build settings then build.

Comment: an important advantage of unity is also that it support multiple platform https://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform this is really charming and loving

Comment: yea, i really liked the multiplatform thing, so you mean i cant even make a simple game in unity!? i didn't know that it was just for getting all the files together..

Comment: it possible, defineatly possible to make simple game in unity

Comment: actually you can make game with only in unity using it UI or simple primitive like sphere, cube etc and its combination it is definitely possible. But you will be require texture etc which other platform will allow you

Comment: i guess your are too new to unity3d. if this is the case then, i am telling you start exploring unity yourself you will understand it automatically. try to make complex obj etc

Comment: Yes, I am very new (I know C++ and Python and know hardly anything bout how games are made, I was getting really confused with different languages and libraries etc.). But thanks, I get it now. You can make the whole game in Unity-but for extra detail for like AAA games, you use other tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if you want to be freer when you want to write your script in game you should learn c# cause it's based on that but if you are new to writing scripts I can recommend using bolt which is visual scripting and you can get the whole idea behind what codes do.
I did this and it helped me to get some ideas about scripting but now I'm trying to write it with c# cause its crucial and c# is much much easier than most other languages

After all, you should choose one which you feel more comfortable with.

and don't forget to use some of the unity ready-project that would help much more than you can think and check their code as well.