# Unity3d - Player Lane Change smoothly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Newbie working on simple game prototype which requires the `player`(attached with `character control`) changing lanes ***smoothly***. Have seen many answers but not able to achieve the desired result.

**I tried using the following ways but in vain!**

1. Vector3.Lerp
2. transform.position
3. tranform.translate

Can anyone suggest a better way to do it?

Comment: If you have a `CharacterController` why don't you use the `Move()` function?

Comment: What about Rigidbody.AddForce()? It changes position smoothly, but can ofcourse cause some problems later on.

Comment: @CasimirRönnlöf  i want to control the gravity so not using RigidBody.addForce

Comment: @Savaria if I use Move(), character control is moving too fast. If I use Time.deltaTIme, I am not able to move the player to  exact target X position.  Player should switch between the X coordinates   - 2.5 and  -2.5

Comment: This is surely about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 1):

```
private IEnumerator MoveLane(float x, float y)
{
    Vector2 initialPosition = transform.localPosition;
    Vector2 destination = new Vector2(x, y);
    float delta = 0;
    while(transform.localPosition != destination)
    {
        delta += Time.deltaTime * speedModifier;
        characterController.Move(Vector2.Lerp(initialPosition, destination, delta));
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

}
```

Start this coroutine when you want to swap lanes, with x and y being the destination coordinate you want. You can adjust the speed with speedModifier (1 being "normal").

Comment: Btw I used Vector2 but you can use Vector3 the same way

Comment: That's not UnityScript.

Comment: @John Yes it is ? Omkar Puttagunta Did you figured it out ?

Comment: No, that looks like C#. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558716/unity-do-i-have-to-learn-one-or-both-c-unityscript).

Comment: @Jichael It's been a couple of years since I used Unity and getting back into it now I can see that C# has become the favoured language, but UnityScript _is a separate language_ made for Unity, and based on Javascript. Since OP has indicated that they are using UnityScript, it seems that your answer won't be of much use to them unless they translate it first.